# jquery autocomplete - windows phone - cant select value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have problem with jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.7.

Users with windows phone 8.1 Lumia 1020 can't click on an option in autosuggest...

Anyone know any solution for this issue?